# How to write java.sql.Blob to JPA entity?

Tags: java, jpa, blob

I have a JPA entity with java.sql.Blob:

```
@Entity
public class LargeData {

  @Lob
  private java.sql.Blob data;

  //getters/setters
}
```

How to create instance of this entity? I want to set `Blob` with `setData()` method, but how to get `Blob` from JPA? `java.sql.Blob` is only interface, there are different implementations for different databases, so I assume JPA should give me right implementation. How to get it?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Use a byte array:

```
@Lob
@Column(length=100000)
private byte[] data;
```

If you want to use streams, create the blob using [`Hibernate.createBlob(..)`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Hibernate.html#createBlob%28java.io.InputStream,%20long,%20org.hibernate.Session%29)

Comment: Additional info to the accepted answer. Confirmed by personal experience in 2016. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16599953/102658 tl;dr:
> length attribute is used to define the
> column length of **String** fields (it is **ignored for other types**)

Comment: This uses a clob for me, not a blob.

Comment: I don't specify the `length` attribute. I also use java nio to read from a file : `myEntity.data = Files.readAllBytes(myPath)`.

Answer (score 5):

use a file stream.
However, this appears to have various complications, depending on your database, driver, and JPA implementation.
I built a generic solution, that was slow, and failed with large files, then found a Hibernate-specific solution that worked with Oracle 11.2.0.4

I'm using Spring Data / JPA, but the issue seems to be around Hibernate, not Spring.

Hibernate:

```
private void testLoadFile() throws SQLException, IOException {


  File f = new File("//C:/tmp/6mb_file.wmv");
  BufferedInputStream fstream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));

  Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
  Blob blob = Hibernate.getLobCreator(session).createBlob(fstream, f.length());

  FileBLOBEntity file = new FileBLOBEntity();

  file.setName("//C:/tmp/6mb_file.wmv");
  file.setTheData(blob);
  blobRepository.saveAndFlush(file);
}
```

Generic Spring/JPA:

```
private void testLoadFile() throws SQLException, IOException {

  File f = new File("//C:/tmp/6mb_file.wmv");
  BufferedInputStream fstream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));

  Blob blob = connection.getConnection().createBlob();
  BufferedOutputStream bstream = new  BufferedOutputStream(blob.setBinaryStream(1));
  // stream copy runs a high-speed upload across the network
  StreamUtils.copy(fstream, bstream);

  FileBLOBEntity file = new FileBLOBEntity();

  file.setName("//C:/tmp/6mb_file.wmv");
  file.setTheData(blob);
  // save runs a low-speed download across the network.  this is where
  // Spring does the SQL insert.  For a large file, I get an OutOfMemory exception here.
  blobRepository.saveAndFlush(file);
}
```

and for retrieval:

```
public void unloadFile() throws SQLException, IOException {

  File f = new File("//C:/tmp/6mb_file.wmv" + "_fromDb");

  FileOutputStream fstream = new FileOutputStream(f);

  FileBLOBEntity file = blobRepository.findByName("//C:/tmp/6mb_file.wmv");
  Blob data = file.getTheData();

  InputStream bstream = data.getBinaryStream();
  StreamUtils.copy(bstream, fstream);

}
```

Comment: works but is Hibernate specific, if you use EclipseLink it would break

Comment: ... which I stated at the top of the post.  I don't like to be implementation-specific, but this was the only solution I found that was both stable and fast enough.