# Does the length field on the javax.persistence @Column define max?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, annotations, entity-model

I have this code:

```
public class Item { 
    @Column(name = "serialNo", length = 12)
    public String getSerialNo() {
        return this.serialNo;
    }

    public void setSerialNo(String serialNo) {
        this.serialNo = serialNo;
    }
}
```

However, the database schema defines the column to be lenght 13. When the item is retrieved via:

```
List<Item> items = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery(SQL).getResultList();
```

The data that has `serialNo` characters equal to `13` (since db table schema allows 13) are still being displayed as 13, not truncated. What is the use of the `@Column` `length` then?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [`javax.persistence.Column`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Column.html)'s `length` attribute is used to define the column length of `String` fields (it is ignored for other types) and is **only** used when the persistence framework will generate the database schema (several `CREATE TABLE`s) from the entities, such as this option (for Hibernate on `hibernate.cfg.xml`):

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```

In your example, the column `serialNo` would be created as a `VARCHAR(12)`.

For all other purposes (inserting or retrieving data), it is **ignored**.

Also, it is useful if you want to **"document" metadata information** of your database in your classes. This way, **yourself** can validate the to-be-saved value before trying to insert and avoid any *"value too long"* or *"data truncation"*-like exceptions.

Comment: Can you paste the link to the documentation about that? This links says nothing about length used only for DDL: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Column.html#length()

Comment: Yeah, it is not too specific about that. Look at the spec (http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html - JavaPersistence.pdf), section 11.2.2.1. That's the only moment they mention `length` in the whole document.

Comment: Clearly mentioned related to schema generation: "11.2 Object/Relational Metadata Used in Schema Generation". Thanks for replying.