# Java JPA where to use byte[] or Blob

Tags: java, arrays, hibernate, jpa, blob

I'm trying to store images as binaries into a Postgres database with Java JPA.
I tried to use `@Entity` class with `Blob` field, which works well, but many people use just 
`byte[]` arrays. see [#1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5032819/2877029), [#2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35507816/2877029), etc.

**What are the advantages and disadvantages of both?

When one should be preferred over another?**

```
@Entity
public class ImageEntity {
    @Id
    private UUID id;
    @Lob
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    private Blob data;
}
```

```java
// create Blob:         
byte[] myBytes = ...
Blob blob = new SerialBlob(myBytes);
```

Comment: perfomance of `Blob`? [Mapping BLOBs and CLOBs with Hibernate and JPA](https://thoughts-on-java.org/mapping-blobs-and-clobs-with-hibernate-and-jpa/)